# warning about pack() while sending push notification from PHP

Tags: php, push-notification

I am sending Push notification from PHP to iPhone.

Connection was established successfully but it will give error me like:

```
Connection Established

Warning: pack() [function.pack]: Type i: too few arguments in C:\xampp\htdocs\BiiMe\checkAvailableProduct.php on line 68
M{"aps":{"alert":"BiiMe finds product for you","badge":"3","sound":"default"}} M{"aps":{"alert":"BiiMe finds product for you","badge":"3","sound":"default"}}
Warning: socket_close(): supplied resource is not a valid Socket resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\BiiMe\checkAvailableProduct.php on line 79
```

My Code is:

```
function pushToIphone($deviceToken, $badge){
    ini_set('display_errors','on');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);



//  $apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
    $apnsPort = 2195;
    $pem_path = dirname(__FILE__);


    $pem_path = $pem_path .'\cert';

    $apnsCert = $pem_path.'\apns_cer.pem';
    echo $apnsCert."<br/>"; 
    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

    if($apns) {
        echo "Connection Established<br/>";

        $payload = array();
        $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'BiiMe finds product for you', 'badge' => $badge, 'sound' => 'default');
        //$payload['server'] = array('serverId' => $serverId, 'name' => $serverName);
        $payload = json_encode($payload);

        apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        //$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('nic*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        echo $apnsMessage;
        print_r($apnsMessage);


        fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);    
    } else {
        echo "Connection fail<br/>";
    }

//socket_close($apns);
    socket_close($apns);
    fclose($apns);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It just coming because I send wrong Device token It just take number,character and space. special character is prohibited.**

`socket_close();` don't Use.

`Use fclose(apns);` instead of `socket_close(apns);`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the line that's producing the given error message is commented out in your code.

```
Warning: pack() [function.pack]: Type i: too few arguments
```

Means that it reached "i" in the format string but there were no more arguments to format. A format string of `nic*` would require at least 3 arguments but you only supplied one.

The code that you have uncommented looks like it should work fine as long as $deviceToken is a hex string.

Comment: So what should i do? and what about socket warning?